# Success and drop

Tags: transactions

I withdraw slp from ronin wallet to metamask after paying the gas fee i recieve 2 transaction the other one is sucess where my slp is 0x9ad5f876caf74af6f5a0f8744df4f3d861559202b9e5835a01bef4cfdcff1c6f
I dont recieve any slp in my meta mask even tho is says sucess and the other one says its dropped and pending 0x0c2dc2aebf2459d6addc4d7c8866ca46335abb1a15c432a3d4f4459e1b65b5b7
How come i have 2 transaction where i only wtihdraw once?? And also i thoght first that my transaction is stuck so i go to my meta mask and reset account since meta mask said if the transaction is stuck you should try to reset account which i did and now i cant see the 2 transaction i did earlier

Answer (score 0):

I can see your wallet on Etherscan and 1379 dollars worth of SLP tokens in it: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9dffc5967a250496d4f4a2a0150ebb62b64f28a0 Are you sure you added the token in Metamask?

It is indeed impossible to have two transactions when you only signed one. You might accidentally accept the second transaction when Metamask popped up.

There are various reasons why the transaction may become dropped. See [this](https://info.etherscan.com/transaction-dropped-replaced/)

Comment: Yes i already the token in metamask.yes i think it is impossible to have 2 transaction when i only signed one but theres 2 transaction appear at the same time and i dont think i accidentaly do accept second transaction. Im only hoping that my second transac succeed and hoping that my slp appear at my meta mask.